# Criar pasta em cada utilização do console

Tags: c#, .net, diretório, sistema-de-arquivos

Peguei um programinha pronto na internet pra criar pasta, dai tentei adaptar ele pra mim porem não estou conseguindo.

Gostaria de cada vez que eu executasse ele, criasse uma subpasta dentro da principal com um nome diferente, e que esse nome fosse o dia em que estivesse usando, daí se usasse o programa 2x no mesmo dia ele não apagasse a primeira pasta apenas ficasse como se fosse dupla ex 19/09... 19/09 (2).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CreateFileOrFolder
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Specify a "currently active folder"
        string activeDir = @"B:\Quality\QAS\FOTOS DO FERRAMENTAL";

        //Create a new subfolder under the current active folder
        string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(activeDir, "19/09/2017");

        // Create the subfolder
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);

        // Create a new file name. This example generates
        // a random string.
        string newFileName = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();

        // Combina o arquivo com o caminho
        newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(newPath, newFileName);

        // Criar arquivo e sobrescrever ele.
        // DANGER: System.IO.File.Create will overwrite the file
        // Se já existe ele pode ocorrer a criação de arquivos random
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(newPath))
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(newPath))
            {
                for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    fs.WriteByte(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // Ler a data de volta para provar 
        // se o código anterior funciona.
        try
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newPath);
            foreach (byte b in readBuffer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        // manter o código aberto no debug.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Diretorio criado com sucesso, Pressione qualquer tecla para iniciar o programa de captura.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual sua dúvida?

Comment: como eu crio varias subpastas com o nome diferente, uma não apagando a outra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o nome é o mesmo ela não será criada e nem apagará nada, não será feito nada, nem dará erro.

Eu melhorei um pouco, mas este código continua ruim.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

public class CreateFileOrFolder {
    public static void Main() {
        var activeDir = @"B:\Quality\QAS\FOTOS DO FERRAMENTAL";
        string newPath = Path.Combine(activeDir, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
        newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, Path.GetRandomFileName());
        if (!File.Exists(newPath)) { //isto pode dar condição de corrida, mas vou deixar
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(newPath)) {
                for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    fs.WriteByte(i); //isto é lento pra bedéu
                }
            }
        }
        byte[] readBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(newPath);
        foreach (byte b in readBuffer) {
            WriteLine(b);
        }
        WriteLine("Diretorio criado com sucesso, Pressione qualquer tecla para iniciar o programa de captura.");
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando [no **Coding Ground**](http://tpcg.io/4OPGk1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rrc7gu). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/PathDateBased.cs).

Comment: Brigadão Cara, me ajudou muito

Answer (score 2):

Para não apagar a pasta e criar uma `pasta(2)`, veja esta função:

```
void CriarPasta (string path)//Cria a função
{
    if (Directory.Exists(path)) //Verifica se já existe uma pasta com o mesmo nome
    {
        for (int i = 0; !Directory.Exists((path + "(" + i + ")")); i ++)//Verifica se exste uma pasta com o nome + (i)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "(" + i + ")");//Cria a pasta
        }
    }
    else // se não
      Directory.CreateDirectory(path);//Cria a pasta
}
```